# Ace Editor autocomplete color.red

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, ace-editor

I am trying to get ACE Editor to autocomplete a list of colors.

Ideally I'd like it so that the colors don't come up in autocomplete unless the user has just types `colors.`.

How can I check that the user has just typed `colors.` before I return my list of colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use splice to get the last keywords entered and check weather the user has entered colors or Colors:

```
var pos = editor.selection.getCursor();
var session = editor.session;
var curLine = session.getDocument().getLine(pos.row);
var curTokens = curLine.slice(0, pos.column).split(/\s+/);
var curCmd = curTokens[0];
if (!curCmd) return;
var lastToken = curTokens[curTokens.length - 1];

if (lastToken === "colors" || (lastToken.indexOf("colors") > -1) || lastToken === "Colors" || (lastToken.indexOf("Colors") > -1)) {
     console.log("Colors found"); 
} else {
     console.log("Colors not found");
}
```

Comment: Cool this works awesomely. I've managed to make it so that the colors only come up when the last token was colors.

Is there any way to make it show up when you type . rather than when you type .r for example?

Comment: Can you check the other answer that I've posted. It should help you in this case